# Usar volley para actualizar periódicamente estado de registros de una tabla

Tags: android-volley

Estoy incursionando en la programación Android. Estoy desarrollando una app que debe mostrar periódicamente (ej cada 15 minutos) el estado de unas cocheras, cuyos estados (disponibles, ocupados) los guardo en el campo de una tabla de una BD mysql.
Esto lo he logrado Usando **HttpConecction** y una **AsyncTask**. No obstante, deseo implementarla con **Volley** y un servicio.
El problema que tengo es que *no se actualiza* el estado de los sitios.   Solo lo hace si salgo de la activity y vuelvo a entrar.

**El código del servicio** que uso es este:

```
public class ActualizarEstado extends Service {
    private Timer temporizador = new Timer();
    private static final long INTERVALO_ACTUALIZACION = 10000; // En ms
    public static BindingServiceActivity UPDATE_LISTENER;
    private Handler handler;
    private StringRequest stringRequest;
    private RequestQueue rq;
    private String url = "http://androidtests.esy.es/obtener_cocheras.php";
    private String resultado = "";
    private String devuelve = "";

    public static void setUpdateListener(BindingServiceActivity bindingServiceActivity) {
        UPDATE_LISTENER = bindingServiceActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        iniciarRequest();
        handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                UPDATE_LISTENER.actualizarCocheras(resultado);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        detenerRequest();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void iniciarRequest() {
        temporizador.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                resultado = getEstadoCocheras();
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }, 1000, INTERVALO_ACTUALIZACION);
    }

    private void detenerRequest() {
        if (temporizador != null)
            temporizador.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

    public String getEstadoCocheras() {
        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest strq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        devuelve = procesarCadena(response);
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("error_servidor", error.toString());
            }
        });
        rq.add(strq);
        return devuelve;
    }
}
```

**El código de la activity** que me muestra (por ahora en un Toast) los registros de la tabla son:

```
public class BindingServiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnActualizarEstado;
    ActualizarEstadoCocheras mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_binding_service);            
        btnActualizarEstado = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActualizarEstado);


        btnActualizarEstado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                iniciarRequest();
            }
        });

        ActualizarEstado.setUpdateListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Antes de cerrar la aplicacion se para el servicio (el cronometro)
        detenerRequest();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void detenerRequest() {
        Intent service = new Intent(this, ActualizarEstado.class);
        stopService(service);
    }

    private void iniciarRequest() {
        Intent service = new Intent(this, ActualizarEstado.class);
        startService(service);
    }

    //Corresponde a servicio ActualizarEstado
    public void actualizarCocheras(String result){
        Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

El servicio se inicia al hacer clic en el botón y luego de eso me va mostrando cada 10 segundos el estado, pero no se actualiza.
He probado haciendo cambios en el campo estado de algunos registros de la tabla, pero no se reflejan en lo que muestra la aplicación.
No se que puedo estar haciendo mal.

Saludos.